# Purge cache in Cloudflare using API

Tags: cloudflare

What would be best practice to refresh content that is already cached by CF?

We have few API that generate JSON and we cache them.
Once a while JSON should be updated and what we do right now is - purge them via API.

> https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/dcbcd3e49376566e2a194827c689802d/purge_cache

later on, when user hits the page with required JSON it will be cached.

But in our case we have 100+ JSON files that we purge at once and we want to send new cache to CF instead of waiting for users (to avoid bad experience for them).

Right now I consider to PING (via HTTP request) needed JSON endpoints just after we have purged cache.

My question if that is the right way and if CF already has some API to do what we need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the purge API is the recommended way to invalidate cached content on-demand.

Another approach for your scenario could be to look at [Workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com/) and [Workers KV](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/how-kv-works), and combine it with the Cloudflare API. You could have:

1. A Worker reading the JSON from the KV and returning it to the user.
2. When you have a new version of the JSON, you could use the [API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#workers-kv-namespace-write-key-value-pair) to create/update the JSON stored in the KV.

This setup could be significantly performant, since the Worker code in (1) runs on each Cloudflare datacenter and returns quickly to the users. It is also important to note that KV is "eventually consistent" storage, so feasibility depends on your specific application.